# Were the original tablets brought down by Moses the same as the second set?

Tags: mitzvah, yetziat-mitzrayim, tablets

We're taught that when Moses brought down the tablets, he shattered the first set in a rage after witnessing his people worshipping the golden calf.

> As soon as Moses came near the camp and saw the calf and the dancing,
> he became enraged; and he hurled the tablets from his hands and
> shattered them at the foot of the mountain. - ***[Exodus 32:19](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.32.19?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)***

A new set was later created which were then successfully taught to the people.

My question is can we be sure the first set of tablets was the same as the second set of tablets? What I mean is do you think Hashem may have changed the laws on the second set upon realizing how quickly we'd revert to idolatry, even after witnessing the events we did? Possibly, the second set being more stern and encompassing more behaviors than the first?

I'm curious if any writings discussed this?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.34.1?lang=bi

Comment: I haven't seen anything which says that the actual content was different, but the commentators do note that the second set are regarded as being more holy - I can elaborate if this is deemed okay as an answer...

Comment: @Dov The Netziv suggests that the second set had the ואתחנן commandments.

Comment: @magicker72 - yes I was aware of that thanks. Check out the Ibn Ezra which lists why the second set were regarded as being more special - https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.34.1?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Ibn_Ezra_on_Exodus.34.1.2&lang2=bi